# Magento 2.3.0 issue in checkout page

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.3.0,i am getting error in console of checkout page.
Issue is attached in screenshot [url](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3909249/e2d581e494734a44f7f9486ddc741c62).

Please help me if anyone face issue like this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That error shows for issue with payment method check.  You have some console showing in delivery date module https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Rfo.jpg , remove those , also try to disable that module or override you tried to achieve and see if the error disappears .

```
rm -rf pub/static/* 
rm -rf generated/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```